# Libgdx scene editor

Tags: libgdx

Is there a 2D scene editor for Libgdx? Like the ability to create the scene and animate it, assign objects fast, then import it to libgdx and start coding?

Basically I want something close to the visual 2D editor of Godot with Libgdx, because Godot is easy but alien to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Visual 2D editor that I know of for LibGDX is [VisEditor](https://github.com/kotcrab/vis-editor/wiki/Quick-Start), although looking at their Github page it is marked as *deprecated*. It should still work though, but you might encounter some problems here and there. Using this you can create a scene in their 2D editor and then load it into LibGDX via code.

It also has support for `FreeType` (TTF) fonts and `Spine` animation.